# java-connector.so not find

Tags: java, linux, arduino-ide

I use a gnu/linux system, specifically Fedora 21 64 bits.
I want to start my arduino IDE by the terminal system, 
and suddenly, this error appears:

> Could not find agent library
>   /usr/lib/abrt-java-connector/libabrt-java-connector.so in absolute
>   path, with error:
>   /usr/lib/abrt-java-connector/libabrt-java-connector.so: wrong ELF
>   class: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)

I don't know what I have to do for fix this error, I've search in the web, but nothing serve for me.

Comment: The library you have is for 32-bit, and you're on a 64-bit machine.  Compile/find that library with 64-bit support.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug details are at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1201871.
Workaround is to uninstall abrt-java-connector-1.1.0-2.fc21 with

```
sudo yum erase abrt-java-connector-1.1.0-2.fc21
```

this worked for me.